# Смешиваются потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, tcp

Имею сервер, к которому соединяются устройства по tcp socket, на каждое соединение создаётся поток. Соединившись, устройство призывается, сообщая свой UID. Далее в пакетах данных устройство шлёт свои координаты. 
Раньше всё было ОК, но когда устройств стало под тысячу, эти координаты стали сохраняться под тем ID что нужно, но координаты не его. Совершенно. С разницей в сотни и километров.
Стал смотреть логи. Суть в том, что когда устройство потеряло связь и снова соединилось - тогда наиболее вероятна ситуация неверных данных. Но это не всегда. Хотя авторизовывается то правильно... Ощущение, что потоки где то смешиваются.
Никто с таким не сталкивался?

Comment: Скорее всего, это именно аномалии многопоточности, но без кода сказать невозможно. Такое поведение вполне легально при определенных условиях,в том числе, если при передаче координат они так или иначе проходят через общедоступный ресурс

Comment: Координаты получает от спутников само устройство и прямиком мне их шлёт. Никаких прослоек нет.

Comment: С этим многие сталкивались. Работа программиста, пишущего многопоточные приложения, состоит как раз в написании кода, избегающего нарушения инвариантов. Одна из самых популярных книг о Java - "Java Concurrency in Practice" Брайана Гетца на 400 страницах рассказывает о том, как это делать правильно.

Comment: Странно, что получается примерно так: соединяется->говорит свой uid->шлёт координаты из другого потока (параллельно соединённого устройства), которые засчитываются ему, а не оригинальному владельцу. Уточню, что uid хранится в памяти до разъединения и берется оттуда же и сапоставляется с хэшем соединения

Comment: Не знал о таких коллизиях, буду читать. Спасибо тебе, коллеги)! Гуглить на тему 'инвариантов'?

Comment: @madJerico гуглить весь учебник. Так как короткого и универсального рецепта просто не существует. Многопоточность - это очень сложно.

Comment: А есть ли такая проблема в пулах? Может легче переписать пулы?

Answer (score 0):

Писал данные соединений в `HashMap`, а помогло изменить это на `ConcurrentHashMap`.